# What does <tt> stand for in Ruby comments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Going over source code written in Ruby, like Rails, I often see that small code is wrapped with `tt` tag, like in rails/activesupport/core_ext/array/access.rb

```
  # Equal to <tt>self[2]</tt>.
  #
  #   %w( a b c d e).third # => "c"
  def third
    self[2]
  end
```

What is the convention behind this, when and why it was decided to use this notation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, my mistake, sorry

This is a part of special RDoc system.

```
Non-verbatim text can be marked up:
italic: word or <em>text</em>
bold:   word or <b>text</b>
typewriter: word or <tt>text</tt>
```

Read more about it [here](http://rdoc.sourceforge.net/doc/)

Comment: Ok, I know there is such tag. but why it is used in comments. Why there are no tags like h1, b, i, span, div in comments?

Comment: Thanks for the link, it is what I wanted, the initial source of the convention

Comment: Also thanks for a question, because before it I really thought this is just an html tag used within Rdoc, but it really has some other meaning.

Comment: It is an HTML tag, that has been deprecated. "tt" stood for "teletype" or "typewrite text", and shifted the embedded text into a fixed-width font, like you'd expect to see with a typewriter or teletype machine. RDoc didn't invent it, but instead uses it for simple formatting, along with `<em>` and `<b>`. And why are there no other formatting tags? Because RDoc does a pretty good job with plain-old comments and formatting, and additional tags would be an invitation to completely unreadable docs. Sometimes added flexibility is a really bad thing because it confuses people.

Answer (score 0):

Found it by myself in the [Rails documentation guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/api_documentation_guidelines.html).

> Using a pair of `+...+` for fixed-width font only works with words; that
>   is: anything matching `\A\w+\z`. For anything else use `<tt>...</tt>`,
>   notably symbols, setters, inline snippets, etc: